# Jquery var syntax. Spltting into two var Lat, Lng

Tags: jquery, google-maps, syntax

I'm using google maps, and retrieving a custom field with PHP and inserting those coordinates into googlemaps using their API.

I'm stuck on the variable not working.

I should start again: 
Can I split the `var co` into `Lat, Lng` Removing the " and the splitting after the comma?

```
  var co = "-37.817852969252414,144.9671745300293";
  var map;
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
```

Comment: you declared the variable as `co`, not `$co`

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. google.maps.LatLng expects two parameters, you're giving it one. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Comment: I think you are right geocodezip, but I can't quite find the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work? `var coords = co.split(","); chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));` (slightly modified from the linked question)

Answer (score 1):

```
var co = "-37.817852969252414,144.9671745300293";
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(co);
```

Should be

```
var lat = -37.817852969252414;
var lng = 144.9671745300293;
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

And depending on the format of `$values['coordinates']`, these two values could be populated by splitting the coordinates by the comma, or if its an array setting these variables like this:

```
var lat = <? echo $values['coordinates']['lat'] ?>;
var lng = <? echo $values['coordinates']['lng'] ?>;
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

Comment: Sorry @pieter I'm not use to pulling PHP into jquery. It doesn't work, do I still need the <?php echo json_encode() ?>;